# How to use javascript string as variable name in django html template?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, jinja2

I have a django view that passes a multiple of values to my html page.
Based on some client side process, I want to process one of those values. Consider the example:

views.py

```
return render(request,'output.html',{
    'k1'=x,
    'k2'=y,
    'k3'=z,
}
```

output.html:

```
<script>
    var temp;
    var i;
for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
        temp="k"+i.toString();
    }
```

Now I want to access value in variable whose name is stored in temp to perform some jquery operations. So I need the value stored in a javascript variable.

Note: the given is just a small example, I am actually using a loop of about 60 iterations, i.e. k1 to k60, So hard Coding if else is not a feasible option.

Comment: Any time you are tempted to use a bunch of variables for a similar purpose, you should be using a data structure instead - an list or a dict (i.e. an array or an object, in JavaScriptLand), and pass it by JSON. `<script>const data = {{ data | jsonify }}; </script>`

Comment: create hidden input fields or assign values using var temp  =  {{k1}}

Comment: would be really helpful if you could give a lil example for how can i proceed with this case.

Comment: You should separate it out into an ajax call that you can get from a front end request

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for data you want to use in your HTML template. Then you can work with it as it would be JS.

```
<script>var data = {{ data | jsonify }}; </script>
```

Comment: cant use this as the numeric numbers in variable name have other specific functions in the same loop as well.